Can't deploy a smart contract: cli 'solana program show --programs' returns nulls
For those who've been following this, I been dealing with ISSUES trying to make a solana-token ICO widget,
basically I finally got around both the,
error: package `solana-program v1.18.2` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.72.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev 

and the error:
error: the `#[global_allocator]` in this crate conflicts with global allocator in: spl_token


I'm quoting these cause I'm not sure if the way I "fixed" these errors is contributing to the error I'm having now.
Fix for first one was:
solana-install init 1.18.1
cargo build-sbf --tools-version v1.39

which forced new types for building.
the way I fixed the second issue was adding,
spl-token = {version = "4.0.0", features = ["no-entrypoint"]}

into my cargo.toml
NOW, I'm having an issue with:
solana program deploy --program-id 86nhbUG4xHaX2KHwAjxdwT6Dgs2x4cbhkXvz8uVyzaP9 --upgrade-authority /mnt/c/Users/Keola/Desktop/MyToken-ICOWidget/Main/ProjectV2/KRPL_SmartContract/new_program_keypair.json target/deploy/KRPL_SmartContract.so --version 1.18.0

it says "deployed"
but, if I type:
keolamation@DESKTOP-RD2S47C:/mnt/c/Users/Keola/Desktop/MyToken-ICOWidget/Main/ProjectV2/KRPL_SmartContract$ solana program show --programs

Program Id                                   | Slot      | Authority                                    | Balance

keolamation@DESKTOP-RD2S47C:/mnt/c/Users/Keola/Desktop/MyToken-ICOWidget/Main/ProjectV2/KRPL_SmartContract$

as you can see it returns null. I'm following chatgpt here and I have no clue what I gotta do cause chat gpt literally just goes in circles saying,

or says cargo clean -> cargo build-sbf --arch sbfv2 -> deploy solana program -> solana program show --programs
if any of that worked the first 50 times I wouldn't be here asking what is wrong. I'm trying to release this token on June 11th and so far I get further and further away from my deadline cause the official Solana devs are as smooth brain as possible..
the race trace error, version clashes, their own crates conflicting with rusts memory management, rustc and solana cli ini versions now being stored correctly across a users entire device, the list goes on. I'm dumb DUMB FOUNDED that any can make a legit non-meme token on solana tbh after my experience. So please, if you've managed to get this to work or know how I can finish mine contact me, all my social media is keolamation and so is my disc0rd.
I would really like to finish this project on time and I could REALLY use some help from someone who's actually managed to wrestle with this infuriating architecture..
Thank you.

Can you check what the solana config get shows? Do you deploy to where (localhost, testnet, devnet, mainnet)?
Can you check the results when you provide the program id for the show program? , i.e., solana program show 86nhbUG4xHaX2KHwAjxdwT6Dgs2x4cbhkXvz8uVyzaP9?
I believe the show program shows all programs of the keypair authority so it could be rather solana program show -k /mnt/c/Users/Keola/Desktop/MyToken-ICOWidget/Main/ProjectV2/KRPL_SmartContract/new_program_keypair.json --programs.
